# Alternate port for Tomcat (not 8080) when starting with Maven?

Tags: tomcat, maven-2

Is there an easy way to specify an alternate port for Tomcat in the pom or on the commandline. I'd like to have several projects running on the same machine.

Comment: mvn -Dmaven.tomcat<version>.port=<1024–49151> tomcat<version>:run 
Example mvn -Dmaven.tomcat7.port=8585 tomcat7:run
OR in POM.XML
<plugin>
...
<configuration> 
<port>8585</port>
</configuration>
</plugin>

Answer (score 109):

I know this thread is old but…

The link to the documentation, provided by Greg is interesting :

```
port:
The port to run the Tomcat server on.
    Type: int
    Required: No
    Expression: ${maven.tomcat.port}
    Default: 8080
```

The expression is what maven use to get the value in its code. It could come from a configuration file, or from the command line.

You could run

```
mvn -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8181 tomcat:run-war
```

Comment: Absolutely!   `mvn -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8181 tomcat:run`

Comment: where should we run this?

Comment: Hi @bks4line you can give the above command in 
select your project and go to Run As option
Run AS --> Run Configuration --> Goals

Answer (score 32):

Using the syntax given on [tomcat-maven-plugin](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/run-mojo-features.html), you can directly specify the port:

> ```
> <plugin>
>   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>   <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>            
>   <configuration>          
>     <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
>     <port>9966</port>
>   </configuration>
> </plugin>
> ```

Comment: Can this be specified within the settings.xml?  This configuration would break others using it if their tomcat ran on a different port.

Comment: New documentation here: https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/run-mojo-features.html

Answer (score 28):

I had a similar problem when I had several small servlets that run their integration-test phase at the same time, which became a problem as those were configured to use the same port. But thanks to the [build-helper-maven-plugin:reserve-network-port](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/reserve-network-port-mojo.html) goal, it is possible to get random port numbers that are available. Then I can create an URL containing *http://localhost:[port]/[servletname]*, which is [feed into](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#systemPropertyVariables) the Java test class.

**Retrieving random port**:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>reserve-network-port</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <configuration>
            <portNames>
                <portName>tomcat.http.port</portName>
            </portNames>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

**Starting tomcat with the port**

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <port>${tomcat.http.port}</port>
    <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
</configuration>
....
</plugin>
```

**Feeding the URL to the Java integration test that is run by the failsafe plugin**

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.12.3</version>
....
<configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
        <integration-test.url>http://localhost:${tomcat.http.port}/${project.build.finalName}/</integration-test.url>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Java code**

```
public class DownloadAreaIT {
    private static final String URL = System.getProperty("integration-test.url");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Below worked for me:

```
        <properties>
            <maven.tomcat.port>9090</maven.tomcat.port>
        </properties>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>${maven.tomcat.port}</port>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: How is this different than the existing answers?

Comment: ${maven.tomcat.port} -> where should i place the value of maven.tomcat.port?

Answer (score 4):

You coud add the port configuration permanently by adding the attribute port to it.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>9090</port>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: tomcat 7, same tomcat7-maven-plugin

Comment: Run as tomcat7:run instead of tomcat:run

Answer (score 4):

There is best and easy way to change Tomcat (not 8080) when starting with Maven

Just Edit your application.properties(if you have no application.properties file, then create an application.properties file in resources directory of your maven project) file and set below line
  **server.port=8181**   //You can choose your port number.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the maven tomcat plugin, you can [specify a context.xml](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/examples/deployment.html) by adding a plugin configuration block to the pom.xml:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
        <configuration>
          <mode>both</mode>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The default context.xml file used is located at `src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml`.

Set different ports there.

Answer (score 2):

I think best and simplest is this (if your test are properly bind to integration phase):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>reserve-network-port</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <portNames>      
                    <portName>maven.tomcat.port</portName>
                </portNames>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
        <port>9090</port>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending about 3 hours on how to change the port in POM.xml, Here is my latest solution.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
  <maven.tomcat.port>8081</maven.tomcat.port>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Using just `port` was not working since that is not  a property that you can set in `<configuration>`. We need to understand what is causing the problem. In my case, error was that port `8080` is taken. I changed the port in `server.xml` to `8081` but  maven does not take it from there. We need to specifically tell it in `configuration` field. This is where `<maven.tomcat.port>8081</maven.tomcat.port>` comes in rescue. Note: You can chnage the port 8081 to something else you like.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old question which not have answer yet.

And I've got the similar question when I need to convert a old project which use outer tomcat to embedded tomcat use tomcat7-maven-plugin.

And what I need is build an executable jar.
But existing answer cannot work for me...
whatever i run `java -jar project-name.jar` after `mvn package`. it's always running on port `8080` which is not i wanted...
Then I search the doc [Executable War](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/executable-war-jar.html)
and what i fixed is just add a param in command

```
java -jar my_project.jar -httpPort 9091
```

which in doc:

> usage: java -jar [path to your exec war jar] ...
>
> -httpPort                    http port to use
>
> -httpsPort                  https port to use ...

hope it useful.

Comment: i think it should be `java -Dserver.port=8888 -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` or `java -Dserver.port=8888 -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` if  using spring boot (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port)