# Tomcat maven error Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy webpage to Tomcat using the Tomcat Maven Plugin.

but i seem error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project ReoWebPage: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2FReoWebPage&war= -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

this...

If i continue to modify tomcat.xml and settings.xml, but i will get the same error.

what's the problem??

pom plug-in

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8089/manager/text</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <path>/ReoWebPage</path>

    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

settings.xml

```
<server>
  <id>TomcatServer</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>password</password>
</server>
```

tomcat-users.xml file

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user password="password" roles="tomcat" username="admin"/>
<user password="password" roles="manager-gui" username="admin"/>
<user password="password" roles="admin,admin-script,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status" username="admin"/>
```

and run enviroment rivse jre -> jdk

i'm use eclipse and tomcat 8.0 
please help..
thank you

Comment: Have you tried to include the `username` and `password` in the plugin configuration? [Plugin Doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#password)

Comment: yes. i tried that.. but does't work and the result was the same

Comment: what are the commands you're using to run maven with tomcat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternate port for Tomcat (not 8080) when starting with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646649/alternate-port-for-tomcat-not-8080-when-starting-with-maven)